# Android native client fails to connect to Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Hey i'm trying to connect android native app with Worklight api i have deployed the server and i copied all the jars and files required to my project then i used the code in the docs but i always get connection failure and it seems there is an exception on the server

here is my code

```
  _this = this;

    buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
    buttonInvoke = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInvoke);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final WLClient client = WLClient.createInstance(this);
   // client.connect(new MyConnectListener());
    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateTextView("Connecting...");
            client.connect(new MyConnectListener());
        }
    });

    buttonInvoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateTextView("Invoking procedure...");

           // String adapterName = "RSSReader";
            String adapterName = "adapter";//m
           // String procedureName = "getStoriesFiltered";
            String procedureName = "procedurename";


            WLProcedureInvocationData invocationData =
                    new WLProcedureInvocationData(adapterName, procedureName);

            Object[] parameters = new Object[] {""};// it require no parameter
            invocationData.setParameters(parameters);

            WLRequestOptions options = new WLRequestOptions();
            options.setTimeout(30000);

            WLClient client = WLClient.getInstance();
            client.connect(new MyConnectListener());
            client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, new MyInvokeListener(), options);
        }
    });
}

public static void updateTextView(final String str){
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(str);
        }
    };
    _this.runOnUiThread(run);
}
```

and here is the exception on the server console

```
    [ERROR   ] Unknown exception: Datasource smartgov/jdbc/CommonShellDS not found in jndi
Unknown exception: Datasource smartgov/jdbc/CommonShellDS not found in jndi
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project RTA_Common_Shell]iDosServiceAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project RTA_Common_Shell]
Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: RTAMHTIBSTGAMX1.rtatestdom.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project RTA_Common_Shell]java.net.UnknownHostException: RTAMHTIBSTGAMX1.rtatestdom.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not knownjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: RTAMHTIBSTGAMX1.rtatestdom.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will not know what is `RTAMHTIBSTGAMX1.rtatestdom.local`.

You need to supply a qualified hostname or public IP address of the machine hosting the Worklight Server.

You probably used that host in either wlclient.properties or in the adapter XML.
Make sure to update it with said qualified hostname/public IP address.

Comment: wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = 192.168.1.2
wlServerPort = 10080

Comment: Well, somewhere you use that mentioned hostname, which will not work that way.

Comment: but this adapter work in this way on ios so what is the appropriate way to do this

Comment: I don't understand your English.

Comment: What do you not understand in "you cannot use 'RTAMHTIBSTGAMX1.rtatestdom.local' as a valid hostname". Where are you using it?

Comment: Somewhere, you are. Additionally, there is "smartgov/jdbc/CommonShellD". Where are you using that?

Comment: this is provided in <dataSourceJNDIName> tag in one of the worklight adapters but i don't invoke this adapter ,also i have tried to invoke this adapter from worklight studio and it works perfectly but when i try that from my app i get an error

Comment: I created new worklight app with no adapters and i just tried to connect with it but i'm getting same result